# Merge Two python Lists with a condition

Tags: python, list, frappe

I have two list Activities and Projects. I want to merge them such that I will be able to loop over the merged list. So now the merged list Appication but I want to merge them in such a way that I will be able to loop through it and check if it's activities or projects and then choose it's fields. How do I do that?

```
Activities

[{'status': 'Applied','activity_name': 'Aasd','duration_days': 15,
  'time_commitment': 10},{'status': 'Applied','activity_name': 'Marathon', 'duration_days': 3,'time_commitment': 3}]

Projects
[{'application_status': '101','chezuba_project': '4','picture': 'projectimage-04.jpg','duration': 4,'time_commitment': 6},{'application_status': '103','chezuba_project': '2','picture': 'projectimage-04.jpg','duration': 3,'time_commitment': 2}]


Applications = Activities + Projects
['acitivities':[{'status': 'Applied','activity_name': 'Aasd','duration_days': 15,'time_commitment': 10},{'status': 'Applied','activity_name': 'Marathon', 'duration_days': 3,'time_commitment': 3}]
 {'application_status': '101','chezuba_project': '4','picture': 'projectimage-04.jpg','duration': 4,'time_commitment': 6}],
'projects':[{'application_status': '101','chezuba_project': '4','picture': 'projectimage-04.jpg','duration': 4,'time_commitment': 6},{'application_status': '103','chezuba_project': '2','picture': 'projectimage-04.jpg','duration': 3,'time_commitment': 2}]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you trying to do here

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your Activity and Project dictionaries into [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), and then use `isinstance(item, Activity)` while looping over `item`s in the `Applications` list.

In general, dictionaries for such applications are okay, but sooner or later it's nice be able to use the full object-oriented power of Python.

I assume that your `frappe` tag isn't really relevant here, by the way. If you really need this specific dictionary format for some other use, you could always write `.as_dict()` methods for your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any indicator you want. I'll demonstrate modifying the dictionary as an indicator by adding the field `type` to both list:

```py
Applications = []
Applications += [{"type": "activity", **d} for d in Activities]
Applications += [{"type": "project", **d} for d in Projects]
```

Then you can filter based on the `type` key

```py
>>> print(Applications)
[{'type': 'activity', 
  'status': 'Applied',
  'activity_name': 'Aasd',
  'duration_days': 15,
  'time_commitment': 10},
 {'type': 'project', 
  'application_status': '101',
  'chezuba_project': '4',
  'picture': 'projectimage-04.jpg',
  'duration': 4,
  'time_commitment': 6}]

>>> print([d in Applications if d["type"] == "activity"])
[{'type': "activity', 
  'status': 'Applied',
  'activity_name': 'Aasd',
  'duration_days': 15,
  'time_commitment': 10},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample that uses a combination of unpacking of objects and assigning a label/classification and merging them into a single array.

```py
activities = []
projects = []
items = []

items.extend([{**a, 'label': "activity", } for a in activities])
items.extend([{**p, 'label': "project", } for p in projects])

print(items)
# prints [{'status': 'Applied', 'activity_name': 'Aasd', 'duration_days': 15, 'time_commitment': 10, 'label': 'activity'}, {'application_status': '101', 'chezuba_project': '4', 'picture': 'projectimage-04.jpg', 'duration': 4, 'time_commitment': 6, 'label': 'projects'}]
```